# Is the cumulative distribution function evaluated on the expected value $\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: expected-value

Let $X$ be a random variable with density function $f(x)$, so
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx=1
$$
and
$$
E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{xf(x)dx}.
$$
Then, my question is if
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{E(X)}{f(x)dx}=\frac{1}{2} ?
$$
and if it is true, how can be proved? Otherwise, which would be a contra-example of this?

Thanks!

Comment: So, the question is whether the mean is equal to the median and this is always true if the density is symmetric about a middle value and sometimes otherwise. For example in the not very magnificent seven 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,  4 the mean is equal to the median but symmetry is lacking. I don't know how much more notation and machinery you want to use.

Comment: Ok! I hadn't see that my question could be restated as asking if the mean is equal to the median. In this case, I see the answer it is clearly negative and I assume it should not be difficult to get a contra-example. Thanks!

Comment: ... take some skew distribution; not every asymmetric distribution has mean different from median but you'd find a counterexample in no time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're writing what look to be Riemann integrals, I presume we're keeping to the case where $X$ is a continuous random variable.

If $m$ is a value for which $\int_{-\infty}^m f_X(x)\, dx =\frac12$ then $m$ is a [*median*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Probability_distributions) of $X$ (if the density is $>0$ in a neighborhood of $m$, then $m$ will be unique; *the* median).

Since here the upper limit of the integral is given as $m=E(X)$, this amounts - as Nick Cox pointed out in comments - to saying "is there a distribution for which the mean differs from the median", and the obvious thing to do when searching for a counterexample is to try some distributions that are skew*.

Here's an obvious example: the [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), which has its median at $\ln 2$ times the mean (i.e. about 70% of the mean).

You might like to also consider the density

$$f(x) = \cases{ 
       \begin{array}{lr}
        0, & \text{for } x\leq 0\\
        2x, & \text{for } 0< x\leq 1\\
        0, & \text{for } x> 1
        \end{array}}
         $$

as a simple one to try for yourself (since the integrations are particularly simple).

---

*(not every asymmetric distribution has mean different from median, however)